# Why are ''WORKDIR /src'' and ''WORKDIR "/src/."'' both used by Visual Studio script?

Tags: visual-studio, docker

This is what Visual Studio creates out of the box

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
    WORKDIR /src
    COPY ["HelloKuber.csproj", "."]
    RUN dotnet restore "./HelloKuber.csproj"
    COPY . .
    WORKDIR "/src/."
    RUN dotnet build "HelloKuber.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```

Why is it using two different syntaxes for WORKDIR? They do the same thing, right? So what the second one wants to protect this script from?

Comment: I wouldn't be the slightest bit surprised if the thinkig behind using a different formulation in the second one was to force a `chdir()` call. But that's silly (pointless, has no effect), because setting up to run a new layer _always_ does a chdir(). Just because put code in a product, even a major product used by a lot of people, doesn't mean that code does something useful or is a good idea.

Comment: (That said, if this is VS _Code_, it's open source, so you could look through the revision control history to find the place where the new directive was added, and any ticket associated with the change -- a result from that investigation will be more accurate than anything you'd get here, unless of course the person answering here does the work for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I got it.

The first one is fixed

```
   WORKDIR /src
```

But the second one does not have to be. It depends, in general, on project structure so instead of just /. it can be some folder name that might, for example, have space.